# One-to-many forms/subform

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables. One that shows customers and another that shows orders. I'm looking to have a form that has all of the information from the customers table and then the order numbers form the order table.

It's set up in a one to many relationship because each customer could have multiple order #'s and they're joined by the customer id.

I'm looking for a way to have a form list each order# in separate text boxes. So if Customer 1 has 2 orders, there should be two text boxes and if the customer has 3 orders there will be 3 textboxes, each one containing the order#. How could I do that?

When I create a subform it works but it's in what looks like a datasheet layout. Instead of that layout, I just want it as a textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the form that the subform is based on and go to properties, on the format tab there is a property called Default View.  Set this to Single Form and you will see the individual form components repeated for each record, rather than the datasheet layout.

CORRECTION:  You want to set the Default View to Continuous Form to see the text boxes repeated.  Single Form will make you click individually through each record.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that out before. When I do it that way, it splits up the order numbers in two separate records. For example, when I change it to single form view. On the main customer form, it will only show the first order for customer 1 rather than show both order numbers

Comment: Commenting again to your edit. I tried that before as well, but it still wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it's pretty close. Right now it show an extra box to make a new entry. I don't want that and even when I set "Allow Additions" and "Data Entry" to no, it doesn't change anything

Comment: Changed`Allow Additions`in subform (not mainform)? If you want to prevent edits too, then use`SnapShot`in forms`Recordset Type`(Data-Tab).

Comment: Figured it out. Had an extra entry in my orders table that shouldn't have been there, which was creating the blank textbox that I though was from add additions. After some additional formatting it looks exactly like I want it to. Thanks!